# Can I calculate all numbers in the interval [0 1] by integral?

Tags: calculus

I want to find the sum of all rational and irrational numbers in the interval [0 1]. As you know, the 0.5 is the center of this interval. All other numbers are symmetrical around 0.5. For example, we have (0.1  0.9), (0.2  0.8) and so on. If we sum all of these pairs to find the sum of all numbers in the interval, we have infinite number of ones. 
Sum= ∞(1)+0.5=∞ 
However, if we use this integral to calculate  (∫˳¹ xdx ) the sum of numbers in this interval, the answer is completely different. Why I cannot calculate that sum by this integral??

Comment: Then you should understand the meaning of Riemann sum which represents the integral $\int_0^1 x dx.$

Comment: The fundamental difference between them is the presence of the "dx" part: **intuitively,** you are multiplying your $\infty$ value "sum of all x" by the " " "null" " " value dx (see that I have placed many quotes around the word "null") giving $\infty \times 0$, and you know that the result of such a product can be very many different things, an, why not 1/2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is: why does it seem when you add all of the numbers between $0$ and $1$ together, intuitively you get $\infty$ while $\int \limits_{0}^{1} x \,dx = \frac{1}{2}$?

The problem is that the quantity $\int \limits_{0}^{1} x \,dx$ is **not** measuring the sum of all of the numbers between $0$ and $1$.  We can intuitively understand $\int \limits_{0}^{1} x \,dx$ as the infinite sum of the product $x \,dx$ for each $x \in (0,1)$, where $dx$ can intuitively be thought as a really small number (an infinitely small number, called an infinitesimal).  From this intuitive picture, you can already see that we are not simply adding all of the $x$ in $(0,1)$, but we are adding things much smaller than $x$.  We are adding the products $x \,dx$, and $x \,dx$ is much smaller than just $x$ since $dx$ is an infinitely small number.  Thus, $\int \limits_{0}^{1} x \,dx = \frac{1}{2}$ cannot be thought of simply as the sum of all of the numbers between $0$ and $1$.

What you can think of $\int \limits_{0}^{1} x \,dx = \frac{1}{2}$ as representing is the area of the region in $\Bbb R^{2}$ bounded from above by the function $f(x) = x$, from below the interval $(0,1)$ on the $x-axis$, and from the right by the vertical line $x=1$.